# where can I change configurations on the fly after User autenticaton in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, elfinder

I am using [elfinder](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder) laravel package to manage and organize files.

It has a `elfinder.dir` config options that used to specifies a directory that user can upload files to it.

Now I want to change (or create) this option to a directory same name as logged in User `username`.

For that I wrote some codes in a middleware that runs after user authentication for limit access of user to admin panels. like this :

```
class IsAdmin
    {

        public function handle ($request, Closure $next)
        {
            if (Auth::check()) {

                $username = Auth::user()->username;

                if (!File::exists(public_path('upload') . '/' . $username)) {
                    File::makeDirectory(public_path('upload') . '/' . $username, 0775);
                }
                Config::set('elfinder.dir', ["upload/$username"]);

                return $next($request);
            }
            return Redirect::to('/admin/login');
        }
    }
```

As you can see if there no directory same as username it will be create.

But I want to know it is right that I do this operations in a middleware or there are another(or proper) place to that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @yannis-berrouag answer and [authentication events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#events) in l5.3 docs I do this.

First I added this to `EventServiceProvider.php` :

```
'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Authenticated' => [
        'App\Listeners\SetElfinderConfigs',
],
```

Then I added my desired actions to `SetElfinderConfigs` listener like this :

```
class SetElfinderConfigs
    {
        /**
         * Create the event listener.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct ()
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Handle the event.
         *
         * @param  Authenticated $event
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function handle (Authenticated $event)
        {
            $username = $event->user->username;
            if (!File::exists(public_path('upload') . '/' . $username)) {
                File::makeDirectory(public_path('upload') . '/' . $username, 0775);
            }
            Config::set('elfinder.dir', ["upload/$username"]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what laravel version you use, but this is something you should do in events in my opinion.

You can listen the login event and do your stuff inside it.